# How to parse nested JSON objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

I get the JSON format like this:

`stream( { posts: [{CHANNEL: {ios: "(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8"} }]})`

What I want to get is an array for the "ios".
This is my code:

```
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
    NSArray *ios_data = [[[dataDict objectForKey:@"posts"] objectForKey:@"CHANNEL"] objectForKey:@"ios"];
    NSLog(@"%@",ios_data);
    dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:ios_data, ios,nil];

}
```

but it return in NULL, what the problem of it?

Comment: The above is not legal JSON, nor is it a representation of parsed JSON in iOS.

Comment: And JSONObjectWithData has an `error:` parameter.  Make use of it!!!

Comment: (See json.org for a description of the JSON syntax.  Mainly the above is missing quotes around the key names.)

Answer (score 3):

Your "JSON":

```
stream( { posts: [{CHANNEL: {ios: "(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8"} }]})
```

Is not JSON.  You can try running it through a validator like http://jsonlint.com/ to test it out.

Also, you should create an NSError reference to pass in instead of `nil` so NSJSONSerialization can vend you an error object.  This will help in your debugging.

---

Here is an example of what your data would look like if it *were* valid JSON:

```
{
    "stream": [
        {
            "posts": [
                {
                    "CHANNEL": {
                        "ios": "(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

(I spaced it out to be more legible, but the spacing is unnecessary for parsing.)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your array holding 'posts' you can drill down like this:

```
NSArray *fileData = [myDic1 valueForKeyPath:@"posts.CHANNEL"];
```

and then access like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < [clientFileData count]; i++) {
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [fileData objectAtIndex:i];
]
```

Also, unless I am wrong, your JSON file seems incorrectly formatted.

Comment: Thank you, it's about my callback json.

Answer (score 0):

Get your response like:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Correct JSOn should be like this

```
{
   "posts":[
      {
         "CHANNEL":{
            "ios":"(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Get the correct format of JSON and then try to parse it. And one thing you were doing wrong is **POST** is an array.

Comment: Thank you every much Rashad, i think i will request some third party to fixed the format or request some another way to parse the data of it.